# TCL pass variable to proc

Tags: tcl

Pass argument to proc, expected result is `puts $cust_id` in `proc` will print the `123` instead of `$cust_id`

```
proc hello {cust_id} {
  puts $cust_id
}

set cust_id 123
puts $cust_id
hello {$cust_id}
```

Output is

```
123
$cust_id
```

Comment: Your proc works as expected. If you pass `{$cust_id}` as argument, the braces will prevent variable expansion so you'll get the literal string **$cust_id** printed. Remove the braces to pass the value of **$cust_id** instead of the string itself.

Comment: If the input is `$cust_id`, it output the the value. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `hello`, you give it a *value* and it prints that value that it was given (because you pass it to `puts` inside the body). When you call:

```
puts $cust_id
```

You are telling Tcl to read the `cust_id` variable and use that as the argument word to `puts`. But if you do:

```
hello {$cust_id}
```

then you are disabling substitutions (that's the literal meaning of putting something in braces in Tcl, and *always* was) so you get `$cust_id` passed into `hello` (and printed).

---

You *can* pass variables to procedures. You do it by giving them the name of the variable, and then using `upvar` to bind that to a local name. Like this:

```
proc hello {varName} {
    upvar $varName someLocalName

    puts $someLocalName
}

set cust_id 123
hello cust_id
```

Note that this is exactly the pattern used by the `set` command above. It is not special (other than that it is provided for you by the Tcl runtime; it's standard library, not language *per se*).

Yes, the `upvar` name is special (it converts a variable name into a variable) and it, along with `uplevel`, is one of the key features of Tcl that other languages don't have.